# Are files descriptors closed when process terminates in Linux?

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, process, file-descriptor

There is a process in Linux (Ubuntu) that opens a file for reading but does not close it deliberately. Is the file descriptor closed by the OS **automatically** when the process is terminated?

My specific case is in Rails application, where I open a binary file. My web server spawns multiple Rails processes. The file is opened from a singleton in each Rails process. I need to know if this binary file is closed automatically when the Rails process is terminated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, closing all open descriptors is part of the process termination routines.  You can see it at the [`do_exit()`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=kernel/exit.c;h=d8bd3b425fa78413f94c9278f481672faebb999c;hb=76e10d158efb6d4516018846f60c2ab5501900bc#n898) function, which calls [`exit_files()`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=kernel/exit.c;h=d8bd3b425fa78413f94c9278f481672faebb999c;hb=76e10d158efb6d4516018846f60c2ab5501900bc#n988) which also, at some point, will call [`close_files()`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=kernel/exit.c;h=d8bd3b425fa78413f94c9278f481672faebb999c;hb=76e10d158efb6d4516018846f60c2ab5501900bc#n457).